# Using row class name in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use bootstrap to a website that has already a `.row` CSS class.

Do I have to change the name of the `.row` class in all css files?
Or can I "tell" bootstrap to use another class name?

Comment: What is the CSS for the current `.row` class? If it doesn't impact/override any of the Bootstrap `.row` class CSS properties it should be fine. Also what version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's row have such styles:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

You can just set all **your** .row blocks with this styles and make sure, that there is no conflict on changing bootstarp's row logic.

```
/* Your old row */
.content .main_section > .row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

But best solution - **rename your old rows**.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `.row` class sets minimal CSS properties...

**Bootstrap 3:**

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

**Bootstrap 4:**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Therefore, if the existing `.row` class doesn't change side **margins** (or **display:flex** in Bootstrap 4), you should be able to leave it as is.